# Neo4j cypher - filter out child nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine the following graph:

[image]

The goal is to query for all connecting nodes between two entities ("Main" and "Other" in this case), but filter out mutual descendants. In other words, I would like the result set to only contain ***a*** and ***b***, but ***not*** ***c***, because C is a descendant of B, which is already included in the result set.

Comment: I do not understand either. What is the exact specification of "interconnecting nodes"?

Comment: In hindsight, it was formulated poorly. Any better now?

Comment: You state that you want to "filter out mutual descendants" and keep only `a` and `b`. But `a`, `b`, and `c` are all "mutual descendants" (of `Main` and `Other`). What are you actually trying to find?

Comment: @cybersam a and b, but not c ;)

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your scenario using this sample data set:

[image: Sample data set]

This query should work:

```
// match common child nodes between 'main' and 'other'
MATCH (:Node {name : "Main"})-[:child]->(child:Node)<-[:child]-(:Node {name : "Other"})
// match the children of child when exists
OPTIONAL MATCH (child)-[:child]->(n:Node)
// store children and childrenOfChild in separeted arrays
WITH collect(child) as children, collect(n) as childrenOfChild
// filter ...
WITH filter(child in children WHERE NOT child IN childrenOfChild) as directChildren
UNWIND directChildren as directChild
// return only direct child
RETURN directChild
```

The output:

```
╒═════════════╕
│"directChild"│
╞═════════════╡
│{"name":"b"} │
├─────────────┤
│{"name":"a"} │
└─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the condition of the problem, then you need to find such child nodes, to which exactly one way to get from the original nodes:

```
MATCH p = (Main:Node {id: 'main'})
          -[:child*]->(T:Node)<-[:child*]-
          (Other:Node {id: 'other'})
WITH T, 
     collect(p) as pw WHERE size(pw) = 1
RETURN T
```

Comment: Creative perspective on the problem! But the use of 2 unbounded variable-length patterns can, in general, cause the query to run forever or run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

This query collects all the direct descendants of the 2 entities, and then filters out the ones that have a direct descendant as a parent:

```
MATCH (:Node {name : "Main"})-[:child]->(child:Node)<-[:child]-(:Node {name : "Other"})
WITH COLLECT(child) AS children
UNWIND children AS c
MATCH (c)<-[:child]-(parent:Node)
WITH c, children, COLLECT(parent) AS parents
WHERE NONE(p IN parents WHERE p IN children)
RETURN c;
```